# What is the best AWS solution for big-traffic websites?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to deploy a website which could have as much as 200,000 viewers every hour, and from AWS documentation I understood that you gamble your instance by bidding max price, so if the traffic is higher than your bid, the instance is gone with all the databases being erased.

Is there a stable solution where you pay for traffic and not gambling the max price???

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "gamble your instance". Are you talking about bidding on spot instances? In any case, the "normal" way to use AWS is to just create instances and pay for them, fixed rate. Their elastic load balancer & auto scaler can dynamically create new instances in response to load. No gambling involved. :)

Comment: So if I launch a regular instance instead of spot instance, I'll be charged by the traffic and computing activity as it is? It won't terminate instance if there is sudden increase in traffic?

Comment: Right. Spot instances are more useful for background processing that can be interrupted & restarted as instances come and go.

Answer (score 1):

Bidding on Amazon EC2 is only for spot instances.

The default is a standard instance which has a fixed price and runs until you stop it or until it fails.

You should always architect your systems so that an instance can fail.

Make sure you're using an "EBS boot" AMI and not "instance-store".

You can read about the pricing here:

> http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to consider using S3 if its a static website as it has massive scale   http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html or just to offload assets feom your web-server.

also you can use reserved instances to reduce the cost of your servers, see http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You can now use auto scaling to bid on spot instances.